# Is there a parser tag for comments in K?

Tags: kframework

Is there any built-in tag for block, line or in-line comments for the parser generator?
e.g.
comment blocks `"(*" Exp "*)"` or inline comments `"//" Exp`.

In a parser generator like menhir, I would normally handle comments by pattern matching with the lexer, so comments wouldn't be part of the AST. Is there an equivalent in K?

If not, what is the recommended way of implementing comments?

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the builtin sort `#Layout` to be the concatenation via pipes of a set of regular expression terminals (i.e., `r"//[^\\n]*"`). Any tokens which lex as one of these tokens are simply discarded by the lexer and the parser does not even see them. Note that this applies only to parsing terms using a generated parser or `kast`; parsing rules in .k files will still require the usual K syntax for comments.

Note that this is also how whitespace is parsed, so unless your language is whitespace sensitive, make sure to include in `#Layout` any whitespace characters which you want the parser to ignore.

Comment: Where can I find documentation for `#Layout`? I tried the `pending-documentation.md` but there doesn't seem to be an entry for it.

Comment: If it's not there, it's probably not documented yet. Feel free to create an issue on GitHub asking for documentation and I'll get to it tomorrow.